# When is the rank of this matrix equal to 1?

Tags: matrices

I am trying to find out when the rank of this matrix is equal to 1:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    2ab       & 3b & 3 \\
    c-2       & a & b^2
\end{bmatrix} $$
I know that I need to find when the two rows are linearly dependent, but it seems like writing out such a relationship would yield me 4 variables with only 3 equations. I know that $a=0$, $b=0$, and $c=2$ is a solution, but I'm not sure if that's the only case.

Comment: You say $4$ variables but I only see $3$: $a, b, c$ Did you by mistake leave one out?

Comment: I meant that I would have something like (2ab, 3b, 3) = x * (c-2, a, b^2) for linear dependence.

Comment: That should be fine. Just express everything in terms of that new parameter, in your case $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have rightly done, express everything in terms of the new parameter:

\begin{align}
2ab &= x(c-2)\\
3b &= xa\\
3&=xb^2.
\end{align}
Thus, we get the following:
\begin{equation}
a = \left(\frac{3}{x}\right)^{3/2} \hspace{1cm} b = \sqrt{\frac{3}{x}} \hspace{1cm} c = 2+\frac{18}{x^3}.
\end{equation}
Further, we get,
\begin{equation}
a = b^3 \hspace{1cm} \hspace{1cm} c = 2+\frac{2}{3}b^6.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid introducing a new parameter, you can use the fact that a matrix $A$ has rank $\geq k$ iff it has at least one of its $k \times k$ minors has rank $k$.

In our case, $k = 2$, there are three $2 \times 2$ minors, and they all have rank $< 2$ iff their determinants vanish, that is, iff
\begin{align*}
b [2 a^2 - 3 (c - 2)] &= 0 \\
2 a b^3 - 3 (c - 2) &= 0 \\
3 b^3 - 3 a &= 0 .
\end{align*}

The last equation implies $a = b^3$, and substituting leaves a system of two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: The system of two equation with two unknowns does not have a unique solution!

Comment: My answer doesn't suggest otherwise. In fact substituting $b^3 = a$ in the second equation shows as much almost immediately.